# Can you hide all transformation items?

Tags: terraria

As of [patch 1.3.0.6](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/terraria-1-3-0-6-is-live.27035/) you are able to hide the transformation effects of [Moon Charm](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Charm) and [Neptune's Shell](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Neptune%27s_Shell).  I combined both of them before the patch so I only have a [Celestial Shell](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Shell) but cannot figure out how to hide it.

Are you able to hide **ALL** transformation items or only the Moon Charm and Neptune's Shell?  I have a Social Accessory sharing the row with the Celestial Shell, but I'm still a werewolf, do only certain items hide the accessory?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the eye icon next to the accessory slot?

Comment: @Chippies I had never even seen those icons.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, as I wasn't 100% sure if it would :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are eye icons next to the accessory slots that allow you to hide the visual accessory effect. It should work for transformation effects as well.
You will still be able to see whatever is in the social/vanity slot adjacent to the hidden accessory, so keep that in mind.